# ClassC with pointer to ClassB that get a pointer to ClassC

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance

I don't really know what to say in my title. I have 3 classes, the first one gets a pointer to the second one that gets a pointer to the third one. I know how to add some values in each (with memory allocation) but I can't get elements from the 3rd class going through the first one. Here is an example showing my problems :

Here is my third class :

```
class ClassC{
    int _int;
public:
    ClassC(){}
    ClassC(int a){_int=a;}
    int getInt()const{return _int;}
    virtual std::string whereIam() const {return "in classC";}
    ClassC& operator=(const ClassC& c){
        _int=c.getInt();
        return *this;
    }
};

class ClassChild : public ClassC{
public:
    ClassChild(){}
    ClassChild(int a):ClassC(a){}
    virtual std::string whereIam() const {return "in child of classC";}
};
```

And here are my first and second class (they look the same):

```
class ClassB{
    ClassC** _classC;
    int _nbElementClassC;


public:
    int getElementClassC() const {return _nbElementClassC;}
    ClassC** getClassC() const {return _classC;}
    ClassB():_classC(0){_nbElementClassC=0;}

    void addClassC(ClassC& c){
        // creat an array base size+1, copy the elements then add the new one
        ClassC **newTab=new ClassC*[++_nbElementClassC];
        if(_classC){
            for(int i=0;i<getElementClassC()-1;i++){
                newTab[i]=_classC[i];
            }
            newTab[getElementClassC()-1]=&c; // add the new element
            delete[] _classC;
        }
        _classC=newTab;
        // delete[] newTab; ERROR WHEN I TRY TO FREE IT
    }
    ClassB& operator=(const ClassB& b){
        _nbElementClassC=b.getElementClassC();

        if(_classC)
            delete[] _classC;
        _classC=b.getClassC();

        return *this;
    }
};

class ClassA{
    ClassB** _classB;
    int _nbElementClassB;
public:
    int getElementClassB() const {return _nbElementClassB;}
    ClassB** getClassB() const {return _classB;}
    ClassA():_classB(0){_nbElementClassB=0;}
    void addClassB(ClassB& c){
        // creat an array base size+1, copy the elements then add the new one
        ClassB **newTab=new ClassB*[++_nbElementClassB];
        if(_classB){
            for(int i=0;i<getElementClassB()-1;i++){
                newTab[i]=_classB[i];
            }
            newTab[getElementClassB()-1]=&c; // add the new element
            delete[] _classB;
        }
        _classB=newTab;
        // delete[] newTab; ERROR WHEN I TRY TO FREE IT
    }
};
```

And a simple main :

```
int main()
{
    ClassA a;       
    addEverything(&a);

    return 0;
}
```

What I want is to populate my first class with the others like :

```
void addEverything(ClassA* a){

    ClassChild c1(1),c2(2),c3(3),c4(4),c5(5);
    ClassB *b1=new ClassB(),*b2=new ClassB(),*b3=new ClassB();

    b1->addClassC(c1); // Adding c1 to b1
    b1->addClassC(c2); // Adding c2 to b1
    b2->addClassC(c3); // Adding c3 to b2
    b3->addClassC(c4); // Adding c4 to b3
    b3->addClassC(c5); // Adding c5 to b3

    // Now I add my 3 classes int the first class
    a->addClassB(*b1);
    a->addClassB(*b2);
    a->addClassB(*b3);


    std::cout << b1->getElementClassC() << std::endl; // gives the right number

    // ERROR HERE, BAD ACCESS, return _int is wrong
    std::cout << b1->getClassC()[0]->getInt() << std::endl;
    std::cout << a->getClassB() << std::endl; // works, give the adress

    // My goal is to do something like that
    for(int i=0;i<a->getElementClassB();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<a->getClassB()[i]->getElementClassC();j++){
            std::cout << a->getClassB()[i]->getClassC()[j]->getInt() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my problems :
`a->getClassB()[i]` is right, `getClassB()` return the ClassB members

So why should `getClassB()[0]->getClassC()` not work ?? 
I want to store everything in my first class, and then display childClass elements

My errors :
`int getInt()const{return _int;}` i have EXC_BAD_ACCESS because of NULL
because of `b1->getClassC()[0]->getInt()`

If you have any questions, I am here. I have no idea how to do it, maybe I have to add one more star to     ClassB** _classB; or I have something wrong with my `->`

Comment: Um. `newTab[getElementClassC()-1]=&c;` - do you understand that only happens when there was already a prior element array (which there will NOT be on the first invoke)? All your initial insertion does is allocate a pointer array of size 1, keep it, and return. No element assignment takes place. That assignment belongs *outside* the if-block where it currently resides (and obviously the same problem in the ClassB version because, as you said, it's the same code).

Comment: I know exactly what you're trying to do; it's still wrong, A mental hop through the code will be near-best evidence of that, with best-evidence being walking it in a debugger. 1. You initially have a NULL pointer to your pointer array (because there are no elements). 2. You enter the function to add a new element. 3. You allocate a new pointer array of size-one. 4. You check the existing array, which is still NULL, so you do NOT enter the if-block. 5. You save the new pointer array address to your member and leave. **No element save happened**. Move that element-save **out** of the if-block.

Comment: Yes you right, in the exemple bellow it works thank you very much. It just doesn't work fully in my true project. II added the 'if' statement today. My project is more complicated sorry.. I'll try to edit it or close my question... Thank you very much though